# The impact of other continuous variable on the DID estimate

Tags: causality, difference-in-difference

I have searched around but didn't have any luck. I am trying to estimate and then compare the DID estimates of the effect of a Treatment on Life-expectation across different Income levels, to know if Income impacts/moderates the effect of this Treatment on life-expectation.

I understand that one way to do this is: 1. categorize Income into different levels; 2.match the control and treated subjects in each income levels; 3. run a DID regression in each of the income levels, the DID regression looks like: Life-expectation = constant + Dummy(Treatment=1) + Dummy(time=1) +TreatmentxTime + OtherControls + error, so that the coefficient of TreatmentxTime estimate the effect in this income level. 4. compare the coefficients of TreatmentxTime across different income levels

The challenge is how to avoid the arbitrary categorization of Income levels since Income is essentially a continuous variable in the population, not categorical in the nature. How to know the impact of a continuous variable, on the DID estimate of the effect of a Treatment? I guess a regression like the one below on the whole dataset does not give me what I want: Life-expectation = constant + Dummy(Treatment=1) + Dummy(time=1) +TreatmentxTime + Income + OtherControls + error. But how to do it correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why no income in the model?

Comment: I am not sure what the coefficient of income in this did regression means. But it certainly does not measure the effect of income on the did coefficient.

Comment: "Income impacts/moderates the effect of this Treatment on life-expectation" vs "Life-expectation = constant + Dummy(Treatment=1) + Dummy(time=1) +TreatmentxTime + OtherControls + error"

Comment: I think you may be suggesting the model Life-expectation = constant + Dummy(Treatment=1) + Dummy(time=1) +TreatmentxTime + Income + OtherControls + error. But I think the coefficient of income in this model does not measure the impact of income on the did coefficient.